# Porting low-level x86 optimized code to the ARM Cortex-A8 architecture

Tags: x86, arm

What are the main caveats in porting C++ x86 code to an ARM processor?

The ones I know / have heard of (but I don't know if they are really a problem, or even true - please verify):

- SSE -> NEON
- 64bit integers become 32bit
- little endian -> big endian

Any other differences and pitfalls a programmer should be aware of?

Comment: Hi, the Cortex-A8 architecture actually supports both little- and big-endian, so depending in which mode you are going to make the processor run will make a difference with x86 or not.

Comment: ARM's are natively little endian and should be run that way.  The 64 to 32 bit might be an issue depending on how the code was written.  otherwise C++ is C++.  if you have assembler mixed in though that would have to be ported.

Comment: ARM EABI which is the most common ABI used by modern ARM compilers is little endian. The ARM CPU can handle either big or little endian.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any decent compiler supports 64-bit math on ARM, so it might be not necessary to reduce the range of your variables. However, ARM *is* natively 32-bit so if you don't need full range then using 32-bit variables will be faster. As well, the 32-bit variables are faster than 8-bit and 16-bit ones, so if you have any `char` or `short` loop counters, it might be worth updating them to `int`s (or, better, `unsigned int`s).

Endianness is generally not an issue - most ARM chips either run in little-endian or can switch between big and little endian. What *is* an issue is **alignment**. x86 is very forgiving when you access unaligned data. On ARM this either produces an exception or (on later archs) makes your code run slower. This is usually taken care of by the compiler, but you need to watch out if you use assembly or packed structures.

Another thing that might trip you is signed/unsigned variables. Until recently, ARM did not have fast instructions for loading/storing signed `char`s, so traditionally `char` is **unsigned** on ARM. If your code relies on `char`'s signedness, you might have some issues. A quick fix might be to use the compiler switch for signed chars, but take care when using library functions. Also, signed `char` will be slower on older chips.

**Edit**: I just stumbled upon a [great page](http://wiki.debian.org/ArmEabiFixes) on the Debian Wiki. It deals mostly with porting from old ARM ABI to EABI, but a lot of things mentioned still apply to x86->ARM. It also links to a nice [FAQ about structure alignment](http://www.aleph1.co.uk/node/294) (although it's not completely correct for ARMv6/v7).